# Selection of Data From Multiple Tables having Relations

Tags: sql, mysqli

I need to select data from Multiple Table having Relation like
A->B->C (A have one-to-many relationship with B and B have many-to-one relationship with C).
[As in given Picture of Database, I need to select sum of total_amount from petty_claim and vendors_claim on a specific Expense type and specific office(Invoice_main) group by Month(Invoice_main.date) click here to view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qj9Z.png) 
Given Below are exemplary tables having no real values but similar to original tables. All Values are Random.
Need Help for this. Thanks for your time

```
Table: Invoice_main
Columns:   invoice_ID   Office_ID    Date
row:       1            2            2018-05-5
row:       2            1            2018-04-4
row:       3            1            2018-05-3

Table: Office
Columns:   office_ID   Office
row:       1            Support
row:       2            HR
row:       3            Billing

Table: Petty_claim
Columns:   invoice_id   Expense_id    Amount
row:       1            2             1000
row:       2            3             1000

Table: Vendors_claim
Columns:   invoice_id   Expense_id    Amount
row:       3            1             2000
row:       4            3             2000

Table: Expense_Types
Columns:   expense_id   dept_id
row:       1            Type A
row:       2            Type B
row:       3            Type C
```

OUT PUT Required

```
Month    Expense_Type   Office_1    Office_2 
1        Type A         1000        2000
2        Type B         2033        1034
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images or, even worse, links to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
 SELECT SUM(invoice.total_amount)
  FROM (SELECT date, total_amount
          FROM invoice_main main , invoice_petty_claim petty, invoice_expense_type expense_type
         WHERE main.office = 'XXX' and main.id=petty.invoice_id and petty.expense_type = expense_type.type
         UNION ALL
        SELECT date, total_amount
          FROM invoice_main main, invoice_vendors_claim vendor, invoice_expense_type expense_type
         WHERE main.office = 'XXX' and main.id=vendor.invoice_id AND vendor.expense_type = expense_type.type
         ) invoice
 GROUP BY invoice.date
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yup.. After some minor modifications.